# How do I remove &#13 ; from my text file using VBScript Replace() or a regex?

Tags: vbscript, replace

I'm doing a conversion between two software which both use XML so the actual conversion part is fairly straightforward - adding text here, removing others here, converting a few information. I'm using VBSCript WSH.

The only issue I'm still having is the darn `&#13;` character - because it's considered an HTML Character, it's not detectable as a string, even though it's a string...

I've tried both `strText = Replace(strText, "&#13;", "")` and using a regex with `Regex.pattern = "&#13;"` ... neither works. I also tried replacing `char(13)`, `VBCR`... nothing seems to detect the actual string itself and not the character it's creating.

Code Snippet from incoming file:

```
<p>If necessary, [clip].</p>&#13;
<ul><li>&#13;
<p>In the <strong>Document </strong>properties dialog box, [clip].</p>&#13;
</li>&#13;
</ul></li>&#13;
<li>&#13;
<p>Click <strong>OK</strong>.</p>&#13;
</li>&#13;
</ol><p><span>To add or edit an advanced paper handling operation: </span></p>&#13;
<ol><li>&#13;
<p>To add an operation, [clip] </p></li></ol>&#13;
```

Comment: You can type inline code with backquotes like \` ... \`.

Comment: Thanks Kenny! I'll remember that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised `strText = Replace(strText, "&#13;", "")` doesn't work, and the regex should be ok too.

Can you try setting these options

```
Regex.IgnoreCase = True 
Regex.Global = True
```

I used this test page and just setting the pattern to be `"&#13;"` worked fine:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscriptexample.html

This only works in IE, by the way.

Comment: Updated my answer, just in case.  Try the regex with vbCr and \r too.

Comment: Nope, none worked.
One thing that does work is this:
`regexp.pattern = "&#1.;"`
The only issue is that it would detect other htmlcodes starting with 1 which may or may not be an issue (I don't use HTML code anywhere else afaik).

Comment: can you post a snippet from your watch window or something of what strText actually contains ?

Comment: Russ, "only works in IE" = fail. I mention WSH, meaning I am not using a browser, I am doing this from a command line (a .vbs file). There are notable differences between both. Possibly this is one of them.

Comment: I was referring to the vbscript example link, the Regex options I mentioned should work in a .vbs file.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to all of this is to use: `regexp.pattern = "&#1.;"` , which of course will also detect other instances of HTML codes in that format - but in my case this works fine.